# How do I handle a series of left joins in Linq to Objects?

Tags: linq-to-objects

A real query in linq to entities against a db like this works just fine. In attempting to unit test the query using linq to Objects I get a null reference exception.

I've reproduced it in linqPad.

```
 void Main()
{
    var _news= new [] {new {ID=0, ExpiryDate=(DateTime?)null }, new {ID=1,ExpiryDate=(DateTime?)DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1)}};
    var _newsRegionSource = new RegionSource[]{};
    var _entitledRegions=new Region[] {};

    var validNews = from n in _news.Where(n=>n.ExpiryDate==null || n.ExpiryDate>DateTime.UtcNow)
        select n;
    var q = from n in validNews

            join r in _newsRegionSource
            on n.ID equals r.ID into rLeft
            from rn in rLeft.DefaultIfEmpty()

            join erL in _entitledRegions 
            // adding .DefaultIfEmpty() here instead moves the exception to erL.ID
            //NullReferenceException underlining rn at rn.RegionID
            on rn.RegionID equals erL.ID into erLeft
            from er in erLeft.DefaultIfEmpty()

            where rn==null | (rn.ID==n.ID && er!=null)
            select new {News=n,RegionID=(rn==null? (byte?)null: rn.RegionID)};
            var materialized=q.ToArray();
        materialized.Dump();

}

public class Region
{
    public byte ID {get;set;}
}
public class RegionSource
{
    public int ID{get;set;}
    public byte RegionID{get;set;}
}
```

Also I tried

- making sure there was at least 1 item in all of the source arrays (but they still would result in 0 rows for this particular query/case),
- wrapping the arrays in `.AsQueryable()`

**How do I handle left joins of possibly 0 rows in `Linq to Objects`?**

Answer (score 0):

Entities behavior is a little different than that of LINQ to objects regarding left outer joins as you've found out here. You can still make it work with a very slight tweak. The trick is in providing a join expression that avoids dereferencing `null`.

My first attempt, I had the join expression:

```
        on (rn == null : Int32.MinValue : rn.RegionID) equals erL.ID into erLeft
```

Less than satisfying since `Int32.MinValue` appears like it is both an arbitrary value and also because it could potentially be a valid value for a RegionID depending on your usage. Another option is to use a nullable int, which I find more satisfying because it provides the same result without hijacking the `Int32.MinValue` case.

```
        on (rn == null ? (Int32?) null : rn.RegionID) equals erL.ID into erLeft
```

Now changing the OR (`|`) in the next conditional to short-circuit (`||`) as follows:

```
        where rn==null || (rn.ID==n.ID && er!=null)
```

Instead of the `NullReferenceException` you should receive the single News, RegionID result now, as expected.